# Problems writing script UNIX

Tags: python, bash, unix

Hey there I am writing a script for my computer architecture class for benchmarking. I do not know what is wrong with the code. I am new in python and also writing scripts.

THnks

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# Lab 4 script

import subprocess
subprocess.call("cd adpcm")
subprocess.call("gcc -O0 -o adpcm-O0 adpcm.c")
subprocess.call("time ./adpcm-O0; 2>>out")
subprocess.call("time ./adpcm-O0; 2>>out")
subprocess.call("time ./adpcm-O0; 2>>out")
subprocess.call("time ./adpcm-O0; 2>>out")
subprocess.call("time ./adpcm-O0; 2>>out")
subprocess.call("rpistat ./adpcm-O0")
```

Comment: Note that the semi-colon after the file name means you'll never capture the output of `time` in `out`.  Actually, `time` is a pestiferous command; it struggles mightily to write its output to the terminal.  You'll probably be OK here, but if you omit the semicolons and the output still doesn't appear in the file, you'll need to do something like `"(time ./adcpm-O0) 2>>out"`, running the `time` command in a sub-shell with the standard error of the sub-shell going to the output file.

Comment: Our code mostly works now, and we've tried your suggestion:

import subprocess
os.chdir("adpcm")
subprocess.call("gcc -O0 -o adpcm-O0 adpcm.c", shell=True)
subprocess.call("(time ./adpcm-O0) 2>>out", shell=True)
subprocess.call("(time ./adpcm-O0) 2>>out", shell=True)
subprocess.call("(time ./adpcm-O0) 2>>out", shell=True)
subprocess.call("(time ./adpcm-O0) 2>>out", shell=True)
subprocess.call("rpistat ./adpcm-O0", shell=True)

Unfortunately, the last line doesn't output anything. We've even tried "(rpistat ./adcpm-O0) 2>>out", but it doesn't work. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 4):

The wrong call ls `cd`, of course: you start a shell, change its working directory, and exit it, because there's no more commands to execute. Yes, each `subprocess.call` is a separate shell invocation.

Also, `cd` is not going to work because it's a shell builtin, not a binary you can run.

What I see is essentially a shell script. Why don't you write it as a shell script?

If you want to time invocations of separate commands, [`time`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time) is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

When you run `cd` in a subprocess, it only changes the other process's working directory—it does not have any effect on your current process's working directory.  You need to change your *own* working directory in order for that to have an effect on other subprocesses, e.g. using [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir):

```
os.chdir("adpcm")
subprocess.call(...)
...
```

If you are running commands which require assistance from the shell (such as file redirections with the `>>` operator), then you also need to make sure to pass the `shell=True` keyword argument to [`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

```
subprocess.call(..., shell=True)
```